# Duplicate Titles needing improvement and/or closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, titles

Inspired by a [similar question on meta.stackoverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104586/156902), I just did [this database query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1802/find-identical-titles-no-closed-questions) on math.se, and found 81 pairs of questions with totally identical title. (Ordered pairs where id<sub>1</sub> < id<sub>2</sub>, excluding ones where one or both of the questions is already closed.)

- In some cases these might be simple duplicates, then vote to close.
- In other cases one or both questions might have a bad title, then edit the title (and maybe a part of the question and tags, if you are on it) to make them better (and distinct).

To avoid bumping to many of those questions to the front page (pushing off new questions), you might do this editing once in a while, not all at once.

Comment: So far as I can tell, the latter case is more likely. I would suggest a gradual editing, as bumping too many oldies annoys some people.

Comment: Good point. I added this to the question.

Comment: adding a user column would make finding duplicates easier, perhaps?

Comment: @Grigory: Duplicates are sometimes also posted by other users. But [here is the version with only questions by same owner.](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1803/find-identical-titles-no-closed-questions-same-owner) (24 pairs). [Here for different owners](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/s/1804/find-identical-titles-no-closed-questions-different-owner) (46 pairs).

Answer (score 5):

In order to keep track of those duplicate questions whose titles have been edited, I copied the output from Paŭlo's first query here. It might reduce the number of duplicated clicks if the questions that have been dealt with are crossed of the list (using `<s> ... </s>`). (Should the consensus be to edit the titles at all).

If somebody can think of an easier solution, please suggest or implement it.

- <s>**Old:** [Bounded Linear Operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1674)
   (2010-08-05 23:30:46)   


  **New:** [Bounded Linear Operators](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38349)
   (2011-05-10 22:28:16)</s>
- **Old:** [very simple conditional probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2731)
   (2010-08-18 19:45:10)   
  **New:** [very simple conditional probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46966)
   (2011-06-22 18:54:52)
- <s>**Old:** [Proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25924)
   (2011-03-09 6:41:32)   


  **New:** [Proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26121)
   (2011-03-10 3:44:53)</s>
- <s>**Old:** [Proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25924)
   (2011-03-09 6:41:32)   


  **New:** [Proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30975)
   (2011-04-04 23:24:57)</s>
- <s>**Old:** [Representations of finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27156)
   (2011-03-15 9:51:44)   


  **New:** [Representations of finite groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47570)
   (2011-06-25 10:58:13)</s>
- **Old:** [Minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29158)
   (2011-03-26 18:01:45)   
  **New:** [Minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29580)
   (2011-03-28 20:46:40)
- <s>**Old:** [Inequality proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29221)
   (2011-03-27 2:02:44)   


  **New:** [Inequality proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47616)
   (2011-06-25 17:31:25)</s>
- <s>**Old:** [Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10284)
   (2010-11-14 19:41:03)   


  **New:** [Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16282)
   (2011-01-04 2:46:25)</s>
- **Old:** [Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10284)
   (2010-11-14 19:41:03)   
  **New:** [Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36069)
   (2011-04-30 19:36:08)
- **Old:** [Sufficient statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21962)
   (2011-02-14 6:06:27)   
  **New:** [Sufficient statistics](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23077)
   (2011-02-21 15:38:59)
- **Old:** [What is the name of this function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/25349)
   (2011-03-06 19:40:53)   
  **New:** [What is the name of this function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41171)
   (2011-05-25 1:16:16)
- **Old:** [Linear transformation - basis/standard basis/linear independendence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33290)
   (2011-04-16 10:32:32)   
  **New:** [Linear transformation - basis/standard basis/linear independendence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33291)
   (2011-04-16 11:11:34)
- **Old:** [Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34365)
   (2011-04-21 19:56:10)   
  **New:** [Diophantine equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/59048)
   (2011-08-22 18:14:52)
- **Old:** [Questions about Fubini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36558)
   (2011-05-03 1:08:46)   
  **New:** [Questions about Fubini's theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52546)
   (2011-07-20 2:03:08)
- **Old:** [Simple algebra question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45357)
   (2011-06-14 18:11:05)   
  **New:** [Simple algebra question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50713)
   (2011-07-10 21:50:47)
- **Old:** [recurrence relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53710)
   (2011-07-25 17:40:25)   
  **New:** [recurrence relations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55920)
   (2011-08-06 5:11:41)
- **Old:** [How to solve this equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3217)
   (2010-08-24 17:59:50)   
  **New:** [How to solve this equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29413)
   (2011-03-28 2:42:21)
- **Old:** [Approximating $\pi$ using Monte Carlo integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5259)
   (2010-09-22 22:36:01)   
  **New:** [Approximating $\pi$ using Monte Carlo integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/19119)
   (2011-01-26 19:27:35)
- **Old:** [differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6594)
   (2010-10-12 6:26:30)   
  **New:** [differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57046)
   (2011-08-12 9:37:22)
- **Old:** [differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6594)
   (2010-10-12 6:26:30)   
  **New:** [differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58137)
   (2011-08-17 19:04:47)
- **Old:** [Evaluating a complex integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23496)
   (2011-02-24 6:50:28)   
  **New:** [Evaluating a complex integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52287)
   (2011-07-19 0:25:55)
- **Old:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45576)
   (2011-06-15 18:28:45)   
  **New:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47290)
   (2011-06-23 23:20:15)
- **Old:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45576)
   (2011-06-15 18:28:45)   
  **New:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47314)
   (2011-06-24 1:32:41)
- **Old:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45576)
   (2011-06-15 18:28:45)   
  **New:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48938)
   (2011-07-01 20:15:49)
- **Old:** [Is this a known algebraic identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4220)
   (2010-09-07 18:35:56)   
  **New:** [Is this a known algebraic identity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32262)
   (2011-04-11 8:23:18)
- **Old:** [Boolean Simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6287)
   (2010-10-07 20:29:39)   
  **New:** [Boolean Simplification](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/6733)
   (2010-10-14 3:11:59)
- **Old:** [Fibonacci identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20948)
   (2011-02-08 5:42:28)   
  **New:** [Fibonacci identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58006)
   (2011-08-17 9:29:00)
- **Old:** [Integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20952)
   (2011-02-08 6:11:04)   
  **New:** [Integration by parts](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/24002)
   (2011-02-27 10:26:51)
- **Old:** [Simplifying a Trigonometric Expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20960)
   (2011-02-08 8:40:22)   
  **New:** [Simplifying a Trigonometric Expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36822)
   (2011-05-04 0:33:25)
- **Old:** [probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22194)
   (2011-02-15 17:31:53)   
  **New:** [probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27239)
   (2011-03-15 18:40:16)
- **Old:** [Minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26455)
   (2011-03-11 20:59:27)   
  **New:** [Minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29158)
   (2011-03-26 18:01:45)
- **Old:** [Minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26455)
   (2011-03-11 20:59:27)   
  **New:** [Minimal polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29580)
   (2011-03-28 20:46:40)
- **Old:** [Formal language problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32163)
   (2011-04-10 22:02:58)   
  **New:** [Formal language problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32256)
   (2011-04-11 7:30:07)
- **Old:** [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38924)
   (2011-05-13 17:10:22)   
  **New:** [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40523)
   (2011-05-21 18:43:51)
- **Old:** [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38924)
   (2011-05-13 17:10:22)   
  **New:** [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41670)
   (2011-05-27 15:58:07)
- **Old:** [Matrix Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45729)
   (2011-06-16 13:45:47)   
  **New:** [Matrix Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56671)
   (2011-08-10 8:29:50)
- <s>**Old:** [Counting graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45815)
   (2011-06-17 0:42:58)   


  **New:** [Counting graphs](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58524)
   (2011-08-19 16:10:14)</s>
- **Old:** [Expectation of an event](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47520)
   (2011-06-25 2:28:35)   
  **New:** [Expectation of an event](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54722)
   (2011-07-31 8:08:24)
- **Old:** [Minimum for this function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9171)
   (2010-11-06 15:51:20)   
  **New:** [Minimum for this function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9277)
   (2010-11-07 15:38:31)
- **Old:** [Convergence of Sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/12769)
   (2010-12-02 17:30:53)   
  **New:** [Convergence of Sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47209)
   (2011-06-23 17:57:46)
- **Old:** [Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/16282)
   (2011-01-04 2:46:25)   
  **New:** [Probability Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36069)
   (2011-04-30 19:36:08)
- **Old:** [Proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26121)
   (2011-03-10 3:44:53)   
  **New:** [Proof by induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30975)
   (2011-04-04 23:24:57)
- **Old:** [Induction problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26203)
   (2011-03-10 15:10:53)   
  **New:** [Induction problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26992)
   (2011-03-14 18:58:41)
- **Old:** [Continuity of inverse mapping of a continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29296)
   (2011-03-27 15:20:35)   
  **New:** [Continuity of inverse mapping of a continuous function](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29863)
   (2011-03-30 2:07:58)
- **Old:** [Differential Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30979)
   (2011-04-04 23:34:04)   
  **New:** [Differential Equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48871)
   (2011-07-01 10:24:35)
- **Old:** [3 variable systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33364)
   (2011-04-16 21:54:21)   
  **New:** [3 variable systems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33515)
   (2011-04-17 19:12:53)
- **Old:** [Simple algebra question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33405)
   (2011-04-17 3:27:07)   
  **New:** [Simple algebra question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45357)
   (2011-06-14 18:11:05)
- **Old:** [Simple algebra question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33405)
   (2011-04-17 3:27:07)   
  **New:** [Simple algebra question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50713)
   (2011-07-10 21:50:47)
- **Old:** [How are TV Texas holdem poker percentages worked out](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57269)
   (2011-08-13 18:22:45)   
  **New:** [How are TV Texas holdem poker percentages worked out](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57272)
   (2011-08-13 18:37:09)
- **Old:** [Parametric Equation Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9797)
   (2010-11-11 1:14:13)   
  **New:** [Parametric Equation Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13751)
   (2010-12-10 2:38:53)
- **Old:** [Probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9824)
   (2010-11-11 6:08:30)   
  **New:** [Probability question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/27974)
   (2011-03-19 16:31:55)
- **Old:** [Combinations question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10835)
   (2010-11-18 12:39:54)   
  **New:** [Combinations question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36188)
   (2011-05-01 10:49:28)
- **Old:** [Combinations question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10835)
   (2010-11-18 12:39:54)   
  **New:** [Combinations question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58991)
   (2011-08-22 13:44:43)
- **Old:** [Solving an equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/10850)
   (2010-11-18 15:49:56)   
  **New:** [Solving an equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/23154)
   (2011-02-21 22:47:06)
- **Old:** [Length of a curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/21681)
   (2011-02-12 15:40:00)   
  **New:** [Length of a curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/49842)
   (2011-07-06 13:58:26)
- **Old:** [Euler-Lagrange, Gradient Descent, Heat Equation and Image Denoising](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29703)
   (2011-03-29 10:52:10)   
  **New:** [Euler-Lagrange, Gradient Descent, Heat Equation and Image Denoising](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51579)
   (2011-07-15 8:03:49)
- **Old:** [Help on a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33833)
   (2011-04-19 13:01:41)   
  **New:** [Help on a proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/44149)
   (2011-06-08 17:43:44)
- **Old:** [Combinations question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36188)
   (2011-05-01 10:49:28)   
  **New:** [Combinations question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58991)
   (2011-08-22 13:44:43)
- **Old:** [Recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/37157)
   (2011-05-05 10:03:15)   
  **New:** [Recurrence relation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/52714)
   (2011-07-20 18:28:03)
- **Old:** [Need help with proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48992)
   (2011-07-02 7:23:35)   
  **New:** [Need help with proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55000)
   (2011-08-01 18:08:19)
- **Old:** [Combinations and Permutations Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/9377)
   (2010-11-08 4:20:55)   
  **New:** [Combinations and Permutations Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/39024)
   (2011-05-14 5:58:10)
- **Old:** [Invariant Subspace Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13120)
   (2010-12-05 17:40:28)   
  **New:** [Invariant Subspace Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/14771)
   (2010-12-18 12:59:01)
- **Old:** [How to prove that this sequence converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/22477)
   (2011-02-17 10:48:03)   
  **New:** [How to prove that this sequence converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58019)
   (2011-08-17 10:53:35)
- **Old:** [Differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29068)
   (2011-03-25 22:15:16)   
  **New:** [Differential equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48502)
   (2011-06-29 19:29:01)
- **Old:** [Sturm-Liouville Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40132)
   (2011-05-19 18:47:28)   
  **New:** [Sturm-Liouville Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40204)
   (2011-05-20 6:33:09)
- **Old:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47290)
   (2011-06-23 23:20:15)   
  **New:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47314)
   (2011-06-24 1:32:41)
- **Old:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47290)
   (2011-06-23 23:20:15)   
  **New:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48938)
   (2011-07-01 20:15:49)
- **Old:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/47314)
   (2011-06-24 1:32:41)   
  **New:** [Trig identities](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48938)
   (2011-07-01 20:15:49)
- **Old:** [2 dimensional Fourier transform integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/54281)
   (2011-07-28 14:38:12)   
  **New:** [2 dimensional Fourier transform integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/55419)
   (2011-08-03 20:18:45)
- **Old:** [Pell's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8503)
   (2010-11-01 6:14:12)   
  **New:** [Pell's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/34368)
   (2011-04-21 20:02:58)
- **Old:** [Simple extension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29846)
   (2011-03-30 0:48:24)   
  **New:** [Simple extension?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/29978)
   (2011-03-30 18:02:42)
- **Old:** [covariance function for Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30791)
   (2011-04-04 2:18:49)   
  **New:** [covariance function for Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30817)
   (2011-04-04 5:05:11)
- **Old:** [covariance function for Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30791)
   (2011-04-04 2:18:49)   
  **New:** [covariance function for Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31255)
   (2011-04-06 4:10:50)
- **Old:** [covariance function for Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/30817)
   (2011-04-04 5:05:11)   
  **New:** [covariance function for Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31255)
   (2011-04-06 4:10:50)
- **Old:** [Combinatorics Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/32037)
   (2011-04-10 7:50:19)   
  **New:** [Combinatorics Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45730)
   (2011-06-16 13:49:15)
- **Old:** [Inverse Laplace Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33114)
   (2011-04-15 7:09:22)   
  **New:** [Inverse Laplace Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33118)
   (2011-04-15 7:51:29)
- **Old:** [An integral identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/33997)
   (2011-04-20 4:22:28)   
  **New:** [An integral identity](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/48874)
   (2011-07-01 10:52:41)
- **Old:** [Matrix Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36337)
   (2011-05-02 1:28:42)   
  **New:** [Matrix Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/45729)
   (2011-06-16 13:45:47)
- **Old:** [Matrix Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/36337)
   (2011-05-02 1:28:42)   
  **New:** [Matrix Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/56671)
   (2011-08-10 8:29:50)
- **Old:** [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/40523)
   (2011-05-21 18:43:51)   
  **New:** [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/41670)
   (2011-05-27 15:58:07)
- **Old:** [differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/57046)
   (2011-08-12 9:37:22)   
  **New:** [differential equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58137)
   (2011-08-17 19:04:47)

Comment: Oy vey.${}{}{}$